How can I most safely read off the end of an array to enable simd vectorization?
I have an array of length exactly 15. If it were length exactly 16, I would have a nice optimized simd implementation of my function. For performance reasons, I would like to pretend that it is length 16, and read one byte off of the end of the array (in a way that the result of my function is not affected by what the contents of that byte are).
Is there a safe way to do this? What is my least bad option?
#![feature(portable_simd)]
#![allow(invalid_reference_casting)]

pub fn find_first_16(
    x: u8,
    y: &[u8; 16],
) -> Option<usize> {
    use std::simd::cmp::SimdPartialEq;
    use std::simd::u8x16;
    let x = u8x16::splat(x);
    let y = u8x16::from_array(*y);
    let e = x.simd_eq(y);
    e.first_set()
}

// SAFETY: y must point to at least 16 bytes of mapped
// memory, though the bytes that are not part of the
// slice do not necessarily need to be initialized,
// part of the same allocation, or allocated at all.
pub unsafe fn find_first_assume_16(
    x: u8,
    y: &[u8]
) -> Option<usize> {
    let y = unsafe {
        &*(y as *const [u8] as *const [u8;16])
    };
    match find_first_16(x, y) {
        Some(ret) if ret < y.len() => Some(ret),
        _ => None
    }
}


#[repr(C)]
pub struct Foo([u8;15], u8);

pub fn find_first_foo(
    x: u8,
    y: &Foo
) -> Option<usize> {
    // SAFETY: Foo has a 16th byte which is part of
    // the same allocation, and is initialized.
    unsafe { find_first_assume_16(x, &y.0) }
}

#[repr(align(16))]
pub struct Bar([u8;15]);

pub fn find_first_bar(
    x: u8,
    y: &Bar
) -> Option<usize> {
    // SAFETY: Bar has a 16th byte which is part of the
    // same allocation, although it is not initialized.
    unsafe { find_first_assume_16(x, &y.0) }
}

pub fn find_first_yolo(
    x: u8,
    y: &[u8;15]
) -> Option<usize> {
    // SAFETY: it's highly unlikely that `y` occupies the
    // final 15 bytes of a mapped region of memory. Even
    // if it does, we'll get a segfault, which is safe.
    unsafe { find_first_assume_16(x, y) }
}

Note that find_first_{foo,bar,yolo} vectorize nicely
        vmovd   xmm0, edi
        vpbroadcastb    xmm0, xmm0
        vpcmpeqb        xmm0, xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsi]
        vpmovmskb       eax, xmm0
        test    eax, eax
        setne   cl
        rep       bsf edx, eax
        cmp     dx, 15
        setb    al
        and     al, cl
        movzx   eax, al
        ret

https://godbolt.org/z/fj168hrPa

find_first_bar definitely contains UB. You're not allowed to read padding bytes.

As far as I know, there is no way to do this, unless the array was originally longer. This is because Rust's memory model sees allocated regions as completely isolated from the rest of the world: in that perspective, there is nothing after the last byte of the array, not even a byte full of gibberish. This is the kind of optimization that really breaks Rust's abstraction as a language. The only way I can think of to make this work is using inline assembly.

find_first_yolo is UB as well. And miri flags both as such.

Incidentally, you can try running your code with miri on the playground to see it immediately detects UB (click on Tools > Miri).

@jthulhu even if the 16th byte was part of the same array, there could still be an exclusive reference to it so not even "the array was originally longer" is sufficient.

@cafce25 indeed, being part of a larger allocation is a necessary condition, but not a sufficient one.

You cannot do it. Period. (Maybe using inline assembly, but your code may fault).

This isn't really possible in Rust because it's undefined behaviour.  Just because, for example, Bar is 16-byte aligned doesn't mean that it's safe to read a 16-byte quantity.  Bar could be located at an address that's a multiple of 16 bytes in an region allocated with mmap, but the last byte is not mapped in the file (and therefore could, in theory, SIGBUS).
Part of the reason you're going to have a UB problem is that the extra byte could be used by other code, and while you'd only have an immutable reference to the 15-byte data, another thread could have a mutable reference to the extra byte and be modifying it at the same time.  That's a data race, and Rust doesn't allow those to occur.
Even if you never write such a data race, the compiler is allowed to make optimizations based on the code as written, under what's commonly called the as-if rule: that the compiler can actually emit whatever code it wants as long as the code functions as if it were a faithful translation.  Because you are not allowed to write code that implements undefined behaviour, the compiler is allowed to assume it doesn't happen, and so your code may end up weirdly misbehaving if you do try to do this anyway.  (However, unlike C, Rust generally tries to make sure safe code can never trigger undefined behaviour, so it doesn't have the giant landmines that C does.)


Bar could be located at an address that's a multiple of 16 bytes in an region allocated with mmap, but the last byte is not mapped in the file (and therefore could, in theory, SIGBUS). -- Is that so? mmap and page faults, as follows from the name, operate on page granularity, and an aligned 16-byte load won't cross page boundary. At worst, you'll read garbage data (specifically, zeros), but you won't fault and thus won't receive the signal. That's still UB in terms of the programming language, though.

